# Design of 3g signal repeater

Tags: analog, signal, design, circuit-design

I am interested in 3g signal repeater and decided to design one. I am planning to just buy 2 antennas and design the amplifier circuit only.

my questions are:
Should I care much about the antennas?
some resources about the design.

I mean to build something like that [3g signal repeater on ebay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/Generic-Wireless-Repeater-Cell-Phone-Signal-Booster/68030/bn_318572/i.html)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you looking at something to extend the range of 3G cellular access? Making your own device do to this would be illegal transmission (and possibly reception) of cellular signals on licensed bands. You can definitely not simply use 2 antennas and a single amplifier, even if it were legal.

Comment: Ignoring the legal ramifications of such a device, this is not something you can just throw together and hope for the best. Based on what you have demonstrated so far you lack the necessary skills to design and build such a device. Sorry to be blunt, but there we are.

Comment: You would only do this as a learning exercise. You can buy complete units for less than the component cost and they will (probably) work without spending 100's of hours in development effort.

Comment: I didn't mean to be one stage amplifier.I mean a complete system.

Comment: I want to learn analog design and that seems to be a nice project base learning

Comment: If you want to learn analogue design, I'd go for something like an audio amp. What you are proposing as a project would require you to learn from the fundamentals all the way through to advanced microwave engineering and RF design, on top of high-frequency PCB design. You'd be spending hundreds of $ on RF PCB manufacture (high-frequency substrates are expensive), not to mention the cost of RF amplifiers.. None of that is stuff you can just pick up on the fly. You really can't throw a few analogue amplifiers together and be done with it. Even connecting the antenna to a PCB is a challenge.

Comment: @Catch.Me this is certainly not a simple/basic project for analog design. This would be an advanced RF system design requiring adherence to multiple sets of standards and compliance with a lot of regulations.

Comment: Well. I got your points, so I will change to a simple radio.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a thing you can design yourself.

There is no such thing as a 3G "repeater" -- home cell network extenders actually act as their own small cellular base station. As such, they must contain a great deal of complex digital logic and RF electronics, and must be configured by a cellular provider.

Comment: Can I do that with a micro controller? anyway I would start with radio.

Comment: No. Again, it's not something you can design yourself. Many of the parts involved are not likely to be available to the public, as they are *only* used in cellular base stations. Additionally, building your own hardware to transmit on cellular radio frequencies is illegal in most countries.

Comment: Well. that's disappointing a bit.

Comment: Can you check the ebay link!